# different result using PHP and Curl to get a web page

Tags: php, curl

If I use this code to get a web page -

```
$url="http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/";
$html = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
```

and then search the page with -

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'download?source=files')]");
foreach($nodes as $href) {
if (fnmatch("*.tar.xz", $href->getAttribute('href'))) {
    echo $href->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
} elseif (fnmatch("*.tar.bz2", $href->getAttribute('href'))) {
    echo $href->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
} elseif (fnmatch("*.tar.gz", $href->getAttribute('href'))) {
    echo $href->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
} elseif (fnmatch("*.tgz", $href->getAttribute('href'))) {
    echo $href->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
} elseif (fnmatch("*.zip", $href->getAttribute('href'))) {
    echo $href->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo $href->getAttribute('title'), PHP_EOL;
}
}
```

I get the result:

```
/freetype2/2.5.5/freetype-2.5.5.tar.bz2:  released on 2014-12-30 21:42:44 UTC
```

which is correct.

If I use this curl code to get the same page -

```
function getPage($url, $proxy) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/ 2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
// $result contains the output string
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

and then use the same DOM code as above to search the page, I get -

```
/freetype2/2.5.5/ft255.zip:  released on 2014-12-30 21:42:56 UTC
```

which is not correct. There is no instance of ft255.zip on the page (using 'view page source' in the browser) and the time difference in the result suggests curl retrieved a different page, or perhaps simply more html.

What is wrong with the curl code, or if nothing obvious, how might I debug this?

Comment: Look at the full response in both cases. Perhaps the web server is sending a different response (i.e. it attempts to send a page customised for the user's browser or operating system etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourceforge offers best suited archive type for your OS, based on provided UserAgent:

With Windows UA you get a .zip :

```
$ curl -s -A "Mozilla/5.0 ;Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0; like Gecko" http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/ | grep "/freetype2/2.5.5/"
<a href="/projects/freetype/files/latest/download?source=files" title="/freetype2/2.5.5/ft255.zip:  released on 2014-12-30 21:42:56 UTC">
```

With Linux UA you get a .tar.bz2 :

```
$ curl -s -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36" http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/ | grep "/freetype2/2.5.5/"
<a href="/projects/freetype/files/latest/download?source=files" title="/freetype2/2.5.5/freetype-2.5.5.tar.bz2:  released on 2014-12-30 21:42:44 UTC">
```

So both results are correct, but you are getting the zip because you provided a Windows UserAgent in `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`.

Answer (score 0):

what is the browser type? .zip is good for a pc. .gz is good for linux/mac.

you can pretend to be what ever you want http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/16/change-user-agent-with-curl/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. The USERAGENT is indeed the issue. As you suggested,
I changed it to -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/37.0 (X11; U; Linux 3.19.3 i686, en) Gecko/20150410 Firefox/37.0.2');
```

and now I get the tar.gz version returned.